# Como obtener un valor de un registro en T-SQL de SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
USE [database]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spPacienteEnCola]    Script Date: 02/23/2017 08:31:26 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spPacienteEnCola]
    @tabla varchar(20) = '',
    @donde varchar(50) = '',
    @funcion int = 0

AS
begin
    declare @VConsulta varchar(max) = ''
    declare @msg varchar(max) = ''

    if @funcion = 0
        begin
            set @msg = N'No has enviado el valor de @funcion'
            print @msg
        end

    if @funcion = 1
        begin
            set @VConsulta = 'select * from ' + @tabla + ' where ' + @donde
            exec(@vConsulta)
        end


end
```

En la funcion 1, que hace el select, necesito obtener el valor de la columna Hora y compararlo con la hora actual, pero no encuentro la manera de sacar el valor del registro ya que el procedimiento me envia el datatable completo, o el registro completo. Ayuda.

Aun poniendo `select hora`, esta bien, me devuelve la hora, pero no como un dato, sino como un datatable. Lo que quiero es poder tener ese datos y asignarlo a una variable con `set @hora = Hora_de_registro_en_bd`

Comment: Seria util que pusieras en la pregunta el datatable que te regresa la consulta

Comment: Hola Anthony, creo que no logro comprender exactamente a qué te refieres, digamos que quieres la columna `hora` y ¿quieres la diferencia con la fecha actual, pero no como una consulta, sino como un solo dato? es decir, que la consulta solo te regrese un solo dato, que sería la diferencia entre la fecha actual y la columna hora

Comment: En realidad, yo solo necesito que me retorne datatable, pero ese datatable poder recorrerlo para sacar el dato que contiene la columna hora y poder guardarlo en una variable. La comparacion de las horas no la quiero hacer en una consulta sql, sino teniendo el dato en una variable ya extraida y compararla con un getDate(). Me explico?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo así te servirá?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spPacienteEnCola] 
@tabla varchar(50) = '',
@donde varchar(50) = '',
@funcion int = 0
AS
begin
    create table #temp (hora varchar(30))
    declare @VConsulta varchar(max) = ''
    declare @msg varchar(max) = ''
    declare @hora VARCHAR(MAX)
    declare @sql varchar(100)
    select @sql = 'insert into #temp select top 1 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),hora,108) from '+@tabla+' where '+@donde+''
    exec (@sql)
if @funcion = 0
    begin
        set @msg = N'No has enviado el valor de @funcion'
        print @msg
    end

if @funcion = 1
    begin
        set @hora = (select hora from #temp)
        set @VConsulta = 'select * from ' + @tabla + ' where ' + @donde
        select @hora
        drop table #temp
    end
end
```

Comment: Hola amigo, gracias por tu ayuda. Mas sin embargo, me sigue devolviendo un datatable ya que es una consulta SQL. Mi idea en realidad es tomar un valor de ese datatable y guardarlo en una variable.

Comment: Edite mi respuesta, espero y sea lo que buscas, saludos.

Comment: Hola Ricardo. Tu respuesta me ha ayudado mucho. :) Gracias amigo

Comment: Te agradecería que la marcaras como la respuesta que resolvió tu duda, en dado caso que así fuese, y no tienes nada que agradecer yo tmb aprendí de esto, ya que no me había topado una situación así, saludos.

Comment: Hola, la verdad es que soy nuevo en StackOverflow y no se como marcarla como respuesta. Dejame ver. Ah Listo! :) Saludos